# Multi-lingual Drupal Site

Tags: drupal, translation, locale

This is my situation:

I have two languages, namely English and German. However, I have several countries that should have different content. E.g. US, UK etc. Now, with i18n you can only have ONE english translation and one german translation.

What is the best way to handle translating nodes in this scenario?

More info:
Location is necessary as currencies are determined by it. The best thing to me, would be if i18n could support several instances of one language, effectively turning it into translations by LOCALE and not translation by LANGUAGE.

Another thing to keep in mind is that some countries, for example UK, might choose to view the site in German. So, ultimately, I would want a selector where you can either chooose country and then language, or alternatively, one drop down with these values:

UK English
UK German
DE German
US English

or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get you halfway there. You can actually create several English translations. It is possible to create your own language which will just be the English that comes with Drupal, and you could call it British English, with code en-uk. I haven't played around with it so can't remember the exact clicking procedure, but it should be pretty trivial.

Comment: I've thought about this, and yes, it will work. But for the moment, I've decided to just have two languages, english and german, and have specific blocks that only display ifUk or ifDe is true. This way there are only two languages present, but some blocks only appear for certain countries.